# Countif() word in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, classification, text-classification

I have Information Gain dataframe and tf dataframe. the data looks like this :

**Information Gain**

```py
    Term      IG
0   alqur     0.641328
1   an        0.641328
2   ayatayat  0.641328
3   bagai     0.641328
4   bantai    0.641328
5   besar     0.641328
```

**Term Frequency**

```py
            A   B   A+B
ahli        1   0   1
alas        1   0   1
alqur       0   1   1
an          0   1   1
ayatayat    0   1   1
...        ... ... ...
terus       0   1   1
tuduh       0   1   1
tulis       1   0   1
ulama       1   0   1
upaya       0   1   1
```

let's say table Information Gain = IG
and table tf = TF

I wanted to count the 'term' from IG if the 'term' is contain in TF 'term' and it's class (A / B) value is 1. It's similar to `COUNTIF(range_term, term)` in excel but I don't know how to do that with pandas or numpy or anything else.

Comment: not sure the python syntax, but R would use filter()

Answer (score 0):

In `pandas`

```
countif=TF.loc[TF['A+B']==1,:].sum(level=0).reindex(IG.Term)
IG['COUNTIF']=countif.to_numpy()
```

Comment: but the IG index only 6, it gave me an error `ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`